# webview is not displaying correct

Tags: android, webview, load, fragment

I am trying to open url under webview. I have the code below:

```
    public class FragmentWebView extends Fragment {
    TextView webview_bar_title;
    ImageButton menu;
    WebView wv;

    public FragmentWebView() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview, container,
                false);

        menu = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.webview_menu);
        menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        webview_bar_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview_share);
        webview_bar_title.setText("Share");

        wv = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_webview);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        return view;
    }
    }
```

And here's my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/webview_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/webview_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/webview_share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webview_actionbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying to load google page in my webview. But it's not working and gave me errors like The website is not available. The webpage google might be temporarily down or it might have moved permanently to a new address. And suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haveconnection to internet?

Comment: yes, I do. Is it the issue of emulator?

Comment: try to surf the internet using the default web in emulator and see

Comment: it's connected. I have no idea. = ="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're setting a `WebViewClient` to your WebView and that you declare the INTERNET permission in the manifest.

To set the client:

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

To declare the permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Those are the only things that I see missing in your code.

Also, it's much more common practice to subclass `WebViewClient` to handle different page events instead of using the default client object.